C++/CLI errors in VS 2022, the IDE recognizes a namespace but the compiler does not
I have a class library using C++/CLI in Visual Studio 2008 and have upgraded it to VS 2022.  The upgraded project generates the compile error:

'AlarisSODLibrary': is not a class or namespace name

even though the IDE is able to resolve the class and namespace references, see screenshot:

I have made sure C++/CLI support is installed:


It seems as if somehow the IDE knows something that the compiler does not.  I haven't worked with C++ in a long time, I have been somewhat spoiled by managed code and I have no idea what could be wrong.  I have looked through the language settings in the project properties but didn't see any setting that seemed to be relevant.  Has anyone seem something like this before?  Thank you.

The answer was to update the ".NET Target Framework Version" setting in the C++/CLI properties settings for the project, since it was targeting a lower framework version than the specified library was built using.  Problem solved!
